# Batch Operation on text files only executing on half of files

Tags: python, text, pandas

I am using the following code to loop through text files and make some changes to them, and then save them to a new folder. For some reason the code stops running about halfway through my list of txt files. I have 54 files and only 30 of them are manipulated with this code before this error is returned:

```
IOError: Initializing from file failed
```

The code I am using is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

d={'Band 1$': '1984137',
    'Band 2$': '1984185',
    'Band 3$': '1984249',
    'Band 4$': '1985139',
    'Band 5$': '1985171',
    'Band 6$': '1986206',
    'Band 7$': '1986238',
    'Band 8$': '1987241',
    'Band 9$': '1987257',
    'Band 10$': '1987273',
    'Band 11$': '1988212'}



pth = r'D:\Sheyenne\Statistics\NDVI_allotment\Text' # path to files
new = os.path.join(pth,"new") 
os.mkdir(new)  # create new dir for new files
# loop over each file and update
for f in os.listdir(pth):
     if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(pth,f)):
          df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth, f), sep='\t', nrows=80,    skiprows=2)
          #replace string names
          df=df.replace(d)
          #sort data
          df.sort(columns='Basic Stats', axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True)
          #save data to csv
          df.to_csv(os.path.join(new, "new_{}".format(f)), index=False, sep="\t")

print 'Done Processing'
```

A sample of the first 1000 characters of one of the text files is:

```
'Filename: F:\\Sheyenne\\Atmospherically Corrected Landsat\\Indices\\Main\\NDVI\\NDVI_stack\nROI: EVF: Layer: Main_allotments.shp (allotment1=A. Annex) [White] 3984 points\n\nBasic Stats\t      Min\t     Max\t    Mean\t   Stdev\t  Num\tEigenvalue\n     Band 1\t 0.428944\t0.843916\t0.689923\t0.052534\t    1\t  0.229509\n     Band 2\t-0.000000\t0.689320\t0.513170\t0.048885\t    2\t  0.119217\n     Band 3\t 0.336438\t0.743478\t0.592622\t0.052544\t    3\t  0.059111\n     Band 4\t 0.313259\t0.678561\t0.525667\t0.048047\t    4\t  0.051338\n     Band 5\t 0.374522\t0.746828\t0.583513\t0.055989\t    5\t  0.027913\n     Band 6\t-0.000000\t0.749325\t0.330068\t0.314351\t    6\t  0.022561\n     Band 7\t-0.000000\t0.819288\t0.600136\t0.170060\t    7\t  0.018126\n     Band 8\t-0.000000\t0.687823\t0.450559\t0.084678\t    8\t  0.012942\n     Band 9\t 0.332637\t0.776398\t0.549870\t0.085212\t    9\t  0.009261\n    Band 10\t 0.386589\t0.848977\t0.635024\t0.087712\t   10\t  0.006628\n    Band 11\t 0.265165\t0.822361\t0.594286\t0.075730\t   11\t  0.004517\n    Band 12\t 0.191882\t0.539559\t0.343836\t0.0'
```

Edit:

The full error returned is:

```
runfile('F:/docs/ESSP 502/Final Project/Codes/try2.py', wdir='F:/docs/ESSP 502/Final Project/Codes')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-95e6eea0c3e4>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/docs/ESSP 502/Final Project/Codes/try2.py', wdir='F:/docs/ESSP 502/Final Project/Codes')

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "F:/docs/ESSP 502/Final Project/Codes/try2.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth, f), sep='\t', nrows=80, skiprows=2)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 474, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 250, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 566, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 705, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

  File "C:\Users\spotter\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1072, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 350, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:3173)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 595, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:5926)

IOError: Initializing from file failed
```

Comment: `os.listdir` includes all entries from within the directory you pass to it, including entries representing subdirectories. Try excluding them by checking with [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) in your loop before processing.

Comment: that returns `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`.  The only files in my input directory are the text files of interest too

Comment: To clarify, in your for loop, insert a statement such as `continue if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(pth, f))` prior to calling `df.read_csv`. In the script you posted it looks like the output directory `new` is created in the input directory, is that not the case?

Comment: you are correct, the output directory is in the input, see my edit, I am not sure if that is how you meant for me to add that line.  Added as it is the same error is returned

Comment: I provided an answer with the correct formatting, let me know if that works for you. And sorry about the previous comment, the syntax was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may be due to including the output directory in the processing and attempting to process it as a csv. Simply omit the directory by editing your for loop to include a check to ensure the directory entry is actually a file:

```
for f in os.listdir(pth):
    if not os.path.isfile(os.path.join(pth,f)):
        continue

    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth, f), sep='\t', nrows=80, skiprows=2)
    # ...
```